# How to Animate this Bingo? want to see ramdom image before to stop and select a image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi guys i am having a trouble in this code i want to animate this before to choose the ball

here is the code 
'

```
var imagesArray = [];
for(var i=1;i<=75;i++) imagesArray.push(i+".png");

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;

function displayImage()

{

var num =5+Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
counter = 0;

for (a=0;a<num;a++)
{
  if (!usedImages[num]){
      document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
      usedImages[num] = true;
      usedImagesCount++;
      if (usedImagedCount === imagesArray.length){
          usedImagedCount = 0;
          usedImages = {};
      }
  } else {
      displayImage();
  }
}

counter++;

if (counter<100) {setTimeout("displayImage(counter);",75);} else {checkmatch();}

}

}
```

'

Comment: Have edited the imagesArray initialization a bit to keep the code short.

Comment: @digitalPBK how to do that? please